# NoScript XSS protection for code snippets

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

## The feature:

The text editor allows code snippets to be submitted as a sandbox like JSFiddle. I'm referring to the button that reads:

```
JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet Ctrl-M
```

...rather than:

```
Code Sample <pre><code> Ctrl+K
```

## The problem:

When I attempt to use this feature, NoScript disables its functionality due to detecting an XSS attempt.

> Cross-site scripting (XSS) is a type of computer security
>   vulnerability typically found in web applications. XSS enables
>   attackers to inject client-side scripts into web pages viewed by other
>   users. A cross-site scripting vulnerability may be used by attackers
>   to bypass access controls such as the same-origin policy.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

## Tests:

```html
<p>This works fine.</p>
```

...however, externally sourced images or scripts do not:

```html
<img src="https://placehold.it/60x60">
```

Comment: I have not seen this with NoScript. Does it only happen on specific posts?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Now that you mention it, it occurs only when external images or scripts are referenced (see section titled "Tests" of edited question).

Comment: There's been a lot of discussion about the security of snippets already [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321652/). There are bigger problems...

Comment: The second stack snippet is working at this time.

Comment: @Rubén Acknowledged. Thanks for testing. I can now confirm that the second snippet is also working on my end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NoScript warns when a request is made containing potentially malicious code in the URL or the request body, such as a `script` tag or an `img` tag.

The actual warning from NoScript in the browser console is:

> [NoScript XSS] Sanitized suspicious upload to [http://stacksnippets.net/js###DATA###%3Cimg+src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fplacehold.it%2F60x60%22%3E] from [[NoScript XSS protection for code snippets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278798/noscript-xss-protection-for-code-snippets]): transformed into a download-only GET request.

As we can see, the raw source is being POSTed to the URL. Similar tricks are used in XSS attacks to have malicious HTML echoed on a page, and NoScript airs on the side of caution to gives a warning.

Since `stacksnippets.net` is a dedicated domain, there is no XSS risk here, so you can safely click <kbd>Options</kbd> > <kbd>Unsafe Reload</kbd>. Or you can disable it for that domain complete:

#### Solution for Users:

1. Click <kbd>Options</kbd> > <kbd>Options</kbd> from the yellow bar that appears, or click the NoScript icon and click <kbd>Options</kbd>.
2. Click <kbd>Advanced</kbd> > <kbd>XSS</kbd> if not already on that tab.
3. Under "Anti-XSS Protection Exceptions", add the following and click <kbd>OK</kbd>:

```
^https?://stacksnippets\.net/
```

#### A Potential Solution for Stack Exchange:

If you were to encode the POST body with base64 or something similar, or perhaps use some other escaping, these requests probably would not be flagged.

Comment: This answer is a work-around until such time as the Stack Exchange is compliant with rudimentary XSS checks. Thank for a thorough and well-formatted answer.

Comment: @ClarusDignus to be fair, there's nothing of value that can be accessed by `stacksnippets.net` as Same-Origin Policy prevents access to anything of interest. NoScript is basically creating a false-positive because it doesn't know `stacksnippets.net` has nothing of value. The CSRF issue from the other meta post is a separate issue, which NoScript is actually quite excellent at solving for the local network.